# Install R package 'xml2' without root access

Tags: r

I would like to install `xml2` R package (devtools package requires xml2) on a Red Hat server but I don't have root access, is it possible to install an R package without having root access? Thank you

I tried to install the normal way as `install.packages('xml2')`. It says I miss dependency `libicui18n.so.58`, so I download the rpm file and installed, then it said it needed `icu58-data` and I installed the rpm. This time it says I don't have permission to install

Comment: Yes. Have you tried?

Comment: I have added to the description above

Comment: That means that there is a developent package whose libraries and headers are needed. You do need sudo to install packages using `yum` and `rpm` but that's completely different. You can install R packages without sudo provided that the development libraries and headers are on the system. For libicui, you will either need to have someone with sudo install the development packages or build them from source and the binaries and libraries to your environment. After that, you can install `xml2` in R.

Comment: Thank you very much!